# What is the technical name of these water outlet cover plates?

Tags: plumbing, walls, sink, plumbing-fixture

[image][image]What is the technical name of these water outlet cover plates? They are found below my sink. The hole in the wall is  bigger than the size of the water outlet so I suppose the purpose of these covers is to cover the hole. I want to buy replacements, but can't find them anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Jack has the proper technical term, but they may also be called "trim rings" by some folk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have always been known as escutcheons. That's as far as I know. If it was for a door knob it could also be called a rose or rosette